# Need to match object values from one array to the object values from another array

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

In the following code. I am trying to get the id of a variant that matches the `selected` objects

```
const selected = [ { "id": 14 }, { "id": 95 } ]

const variants = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "option_values": [ { "id": 7 }, { "id": 95, } ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "option_values": [ { "id": 8 }, { "id": 95, } ]
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "option_values": [ { "id": 14 }, { "id": 95, } ]
  }
]

function filterVaiant() {
    return variants.filter( options => {
        // return id 3 because it matches the selected objects
    });
}

console.log(filterVaiant());
```

The filter function should return variant `id:3` because it has the same option values as the selected option values.

## follow up

```
const colors = require('colors');

const selected = [ { "id": 14 }, { "id": 95 }, { "id": 21 } ]

let selected_ids  = selected.map(e=>e.id);

const variants = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "option_values": [ { "id": 7 }, { "id": 95, } ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "option_values": [ { "id": 8 }, { "id": 95, } ]
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "option_values": [ { "id": 14 }, { "id": 95, } ]
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "option_values": [ { "id": 14 }, { "id": 95, }, { "id": 21 } ]
  }
]

let vID = variants.filter(e=> e.option_values.every(e=> selected_ids.indexOf(e.id) > -1));

console.log("answer:",vID) // Returns 3 and 4 but should only return 4
```

in this scenario `vID` is 3 and 4 but should only return 4 because it is the only one that matches the selections exactly.

Comment: Do the list of Ids all have to match, or just at least one?

Comment: Great answer. have you seen the follow up question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.filter` and [**`.every`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) to achieve this like

```js
const selected = [ { "id": 14 }, { "id": 95 } ];

var ids  = selected.map(e=>e.id);


const variants = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "option_values": [ { "id": 7 }, { "id": 95, } ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "option_values": [ { "id": 8 }, { "id": 95, } ]
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "option_values": [ { "id": 14 }, { "id": 95, } ]
  }
];

var o = variants.filter(e=> e.option_values.every(e=> ids.indexOf(e.id) > -1));

console.log(o)
```

What's happening here is, get all the selected ids in an array, then filter the `variants` array based on if every entry of `option_values` has all the entries as the `selected` ids.

Comment: It returns (incorrectly?) a variant even if `option_values` is a subsect of `selected`. Not clear if this could be a case

Comment: _if option_values is a subsect of selected_ Yes, in this case if would return that variant

Comment: @GeorgeBailey thank you for this answer! CAn you take a look at the follow up question? I updated my question.

Comment: try this `variants.filter(e=> e.option_values.every(e=> ids.indexOf(e.id) > -1) && e.option_values.length === selected.length);`

Answer (score 2):

For each object, check that *all* items in `selected` appear in `option_values` (`ops` alias) by checking that the length is equal, and using [`Array.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every), and [`Array.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find):

```js
const selected = [ { "id": 14 }, { "id": 95 } ]

const variants = [{"id":1,"option_values":[{"id":7},{"id":95}]},{"id":2,"option_values":[{"id":8},{"id":95}]},{"id":3,"option_values":[{"id":14},{"id":95}]}];

function filterVaiant() {
  return variants.filter(({ option_values: ops }) => {
    if (selected.length !== ops.length) return false;
    return selected.every(({ id }) => 
      ops.find((o) => id === o.id));
  });
}

console.log(filterVaiant());
```

Answer (score 2):

Using a Set to store the selected Id's to look up and Array#every in a filter

```js
const selected = [ { "id": 14 }, { "id": 95 } ]

const variants = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "option_values": [ { "id": 7 }, { "id": 95, } ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "option_values": [ { "id": 8 }, { "id": 95, } ]
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "option_values": [ { "id": 14 }, { "id": 95, } ]
  }
]

function filterVaiant(selected) {
    let ids = new Set(selected.map(({id})=>id))
    return variants.filter( o => o.option_values.every(({id})=>ids.has(id)));
}

console.log(filterVaiant(selected));
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution with **map** only **indexof** and **join**:

```js
const selected = [ { "id": 14 }, { "id": 95 } ]


const variants = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "option_values": [ { "id": 7 }, { "id": 95, } ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "option_values": [ { "id": 8 }, { "id": 95, } ]
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "option_values": [ { "id": 14 }, { "id": 95, } ]
  }
]

function filterVaiant(selected) {
    return variants[variants.map(obj => obj.option_values).map(outterarray => outterarray.map(innerArray=>innerArray.id).join('-') ).indexOf(selected.map(eb=>eb.id).join('-'))];
}

console.log(filterVaiant(selected));
```